# Where should I put menu items in MVC with PHP - Model or Controller?

Tags: php, mvc, codeigniter

This is my first attempt with MVC and I almost get it, but a small thing bothers me.

I have this controller in CodeIgniter:

```
<?php
class Page extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($page = "home")
    {
            $data['page'] = $page;
            list($data['title']) = array_keys($this->_menu(), $page);
            $data['menuItems'] = $this->_menu();

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/menu', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

    private function _menu()
    {
        static $menuItems = array(
                           "Home page" => "home",
                           "Our history" => "history",
                           "About us" => "about",
                           "Contact page" => "contact"
                       );

        return $menuItems;
    }
}
```

And here is the menu view:

```
<?php
$menu = "";
foreach ($menuItems as $menuName => $view) {
    $menu .= '<li';
    if ( $page == $view ) {
        $menu .= ' class="selected">';
        $menu .= '<a href="#">';
    } else {
        $menu .= '><a href="' . $view . '">';
    }
    $menu .= $menuName . '</a></li>' .PHP_EOL ;
}

echo $menu;
```

Where do the menu items belong in MVC logic?  Is it ok to store things like the menu in the `Controller` or do I have to make a new `Model` for it like this?

```
class Menu extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_menu_items()
    {
        static $menuItems = array(
                           "Home page" => "home",
                           "Our history" => "history",
                           "About us" => "about",
                           "Contact page" => "contact"
                       );

        return $menuItems;  
    }
}
```

Then load it from `Controller`:

```
public function index($page = "home")
{
    ...
    $this->load->model('Menu');
    $data['menuItems'] = $this->Menu->get_menu_items();

    $this->load->view(...);
    $this->load->view(...);
    $this->load->view(...);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a nice example: it shows how the MVC is just a pattern which should be ajusted to your needs.

- The menu items you're showing seem *very unlikely* to change over time. This means you can simply put them in your "templates/menu" **view**.
- If they're shared among multiple views, then the **controller** is OK.
- If the menu items can change dynamically, then your model can provide a meaningful abstraction over your data, and then it would go into a **model**.

Comment: So if I get the menu elements from database, it should go to model, right ?
How can I set page title if I put the array into the view ?
`list($data['title']) = array_keys($this->_menu(), $page);`
I cannot acces the menu items from the controller then. Or can I ?

Comment: `$data['menuItems']` becomes `$menuItems` in the view. So if you want to use `array_keys`, simply use `array_keys($menuItems, "about")` to get "About us". By the way, it would make more sense for "about" to be the key, and "About us" to be the value. You could then write `$menuItems["about"]`. Why don't you simply use a foreach over `$menuItems`?

Comment: I want the active page menu item to look different, so I mark the active menu with `selected` class.
In my question I meant that If I put the menu elements array in the view, not the controller, I can't determine what is the actual page title, so it have to reachable from the controller to assign `$data['title']` based on which page is active.

Comment: Ah! Simply set `$data['page'] = $page;`?

Comment: I want "About us" to be the page title in the browser tab, not "about". And I cannot if I put the array in the view.

Comment: Since `templates/header` does not know about `$menuItems`, but `templates/menu` does? That's the second bullet point of my answer.